# Quickest way to calculate Expectation of the minimum of n rolls of an s sided die?

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

Forgive me as I never studied Probability

I have successfully calcuated the expectation of the minimum

For the n = 2 , s = 6 case

$Z=Min\left( X_{1},X_{2}\right) $

I calculated the expectation of the minimum using the Tails Sum formula :

$E\left( z\right) =\sum ^{6}_{k=1}P\left( x\geq k\right) $ = $\sum ^{6}_{i=1}\left( \dfrac {7-i}{6}\right) ^{2}$

and then also I calculated it with the CDF and then using $f_{z}\left( x\right) =F_{z}\left( x\right) -F_{z}\left( x-1\right) $ = $\dfrac {1}{36}\left( \left( 7-y\right) ^{2}-\left( 6-y^{2}\right) \right) $

so $E\left( z\right)$ = $\sum ^{6}_{y=1}yf_{z}\left( y\right) $

I was wondering a) Are there quicker ways than this?

b) What is the relation with the maximum and minimum expectation, as the formulas seem very similar.

c) Does this generalise to n rolls and s sides

So for $Z=Min\left( X_{1},...,X_{n}\right) $

$E\left( Z\right) =\sum ^{s}_{k=1}P\left( x\geq k\right) $ = $\sum ^{s}_{i=1}\left( \dfrac {(s+1)-i}{s}\right) ^{n}$ ?

From another post I know the maximum is 
$$E[X]=\boxed{s-s^{-n}\sum_{i=1}^{s-1}i^n}.$$

Is there a simple relation between the expectations of the maximum and minimum of n die rolls?

Comment: Yes, it should be $s+1\ -\ \mathrm E(\min) $.

Comment: What is your pmf of $Z$? I have $f_z(z)=\frac{-2z+13}{36} \mathbb I_{1\leq z\leq 6}$. I don´t see that yours is the same.

Comment: @Callculus, Yes it is the same. DId you not derive yours from $f_{z}\left( z\right) =F_{z}\left( z\right) -F_{z}\left( z-1\right) $ = $\dfrac {1}{36}\left( \left( 7-z\right) ^{2}-\left( 6-z^{2}\right) \right) $

Comment: @Berci, Ok I believe you, is that easy to see?

Comment: So that means my general formula, for the Expectation of the minimum is wrong?$\sum ^{s}_{i=1}\left( \dfrac {(s+1)-i}{s}\right) ^{n}$